# Want to retrieve only unique nodes from XML using XQUERY

Tags: xquery, xquery-sql

I have XML as follows:

```
<Root>  
    <Inv><Id>1</Id><Name>John</Name></Inv>
    <Inv><Id>2</Id><Name>Tom</Name></Inv>
    <Inv><Id>1</Id><Name>John</Name></Inv>
    <Inv><Id>4</Id><Name>Harry</Name></Inv>

</Root>
```

Want to retrieve only unique nodes using XQUERY.

Could you please guide?

Comment: http://atomic.exist-db.org/HowTo/XQuery3/GroupByClause

Comment: @NaveedS  - Thank you Naveed. What if I have more than 1 <Root> tags saved in Database and I want to retrive it. Thus I have one <Root> tag saved in one row and other in second row.

Comment: Hi, Its not working for me, could you help me?

Comment: Actually I'm new to xquery and I couldn't exactly identify the proper solution to your problem. That's why I suggested the link instead of posting the answer. Let me try to figure out something. Not sure whether I can help you. Sorry.

Comment: What is your criteria for "unique nodes"? Do you mean that you want a distinct list of `<Inv>` elements? Can you describe your criteria and show an example of the output that you are trying to generate from the sample input?

Answer (score 1):

The following XQuery produces a distinct list of `<Inv>` elements by performing a [`deep-equal()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-deep-equal) comparison of the sequence of `<Inv>` elements:

```
let $invSequence := /Root/Inv
(:
  For each position(),
  return the <inv> element who's position is equal to the current number,
  and who's previous siblings are not deep-equal() 
:)
for $pos in (1 to count($invSequence))
return $invSequence[$pos] 
                    [not(some $inv in $invSequence[position() < $pos] 
                           satisfies deep-equal(., $inv))]
```

**The result:**

```
<Inv>
   <Id>1</Id>
   <Name>John</Name>
</Inv>
<Inv>
   <Id>2</Id>
   <Name>Tom</Name>
</Inv>
<Inv>
   <Id>4</Id>
   <Name>Harry</Name>
</Inv>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the structure and only have two child elements of `<Id>` and `<Name>`, then you could group by those elements and select the first one from the group:

```
for $inv in /Root/Inv
  let $id := $inv/Id
  let $name := $inv/Name
  group by $id, $name
return $inv[1]
```